# The meanings of different forms of letter R

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

The latin letter R has many different forms, such as $R$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{R}$, $\mathfrak{R}$, and $\mathscr{R}$.

To represent a vector $x$ of dimension $n$, I have seen $x \in R^n$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $x \in \mathcal{R}^n$, even $x \in \mathfrak{R}^n$. Which one is most common?

Where can I find an explain of different meaning of those different forms?

Comment: I prefer $\mathbb R^n$, but I've seen $\mathcal R^n$. Haven't seen $\mathfrak R^n$, that's pretty unusual.

Comment: As a rule, symbols devoid of context have no meaning. And strictly speaking, it is senseless to call one “correct”, as if there were some single answer.  And in the one context you named, these symbols probably all mean “the real numbers”, so there is no difference.  Did you mean to ask something more like which version is most common?

Comment: Wait until you see $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space) says :

> In mathematics, real coordinate space of n dimensions, written Rn (/ɑːrˈɛn/ ar-EN) (also written ℝn with blackboard bold) is a coordinate space that allows several (n) real variables to be treated as a single variable.

So, i guess, both R and ℝ are correct. However, I've seen this ℝ used at most of the places.